# Xamarin Application does not start up when CollectionView is included in ScrollView and ScrollView's Visible is False

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I stuck into vary strange issue.

I have vary simple layout like below,

```
<ScrollView>
    <CollectionView />
</ScrollView>
```

And I just changed `ScrollView.IsVisible = False` and then my application does not response when try to load main page on **iOS** device.

- Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1451

#### XAML

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:CollectionViewTest"
    x:Class="CollectionViewTest.MainPage">
        <ScrollView IsVisible="False">
        <CollectionView
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource}"
            SelectionMode="Single">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="4"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="10"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image
                        Source="{Test:ImageResource CollectionViewTest.waterfront.jpg}"
                        Aspect="AspectFit"
                        WidthRequest="70"
                        HeightRequest="70"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

        </CollectionView>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

#### ViewModel

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<object> _itemSource;
    public ObservableCollection<object> ItemSource => _itemSource;

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        _itemSource = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
            _itemSource.Add(new object());
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Full source code is on [Github](https://github.com/ibocon/StackOverflow/tree/63951109)

Comment: It seems an existing issue of ScrollView. Why did you set the IsVisible as False in default ?It would better to use data binding and set the value to false after loading page .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Original source code use data binding. I just made a clear sample for question.

Comment: It seems an existing issue of ScrollView (When use StackLayout and Grid it works fine) . You could post the issue https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues and share the link  .We will focus on it .